# How to fix arguments linter error in binder?

Tags: javascript, arguments, linter

I need a function that has same functionality as Function.prototype.bind().  I have:

```
export function customBind(func, context, ...args) {
  const bindArgs = [].slice.call(arguments, 2);

  return function() {
    const funcArgs = [].slice.call(arguments);

    return func.apply(context, bindArgs.concat(funcArgs), ...args);
  };
}
```

And error:

```
error    Use the rest parameters instead of 'arguments'  prefer-rest-params
```

How I can change arguments on smth else? Just tried with args but that isn't correct.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-rest-params)?

Comment: Of course, first that I did